# Computer freeze on battery startup (crash) only

Tags: windows, freeze

[image: screen dump attempted repair]MSI Computer, GS 70.

Replaced battery, and on startup boot, computer crashes on start with battery only.  Boots fine when going to plug in.

After start, computer will run fine on battery.  No idea, since the battery install was correct, and this is a factory battery, not knock off.

- Windows 7
- Core 7 processor
- 2 SSD drives 1/2 TB...

No errors or drive problems.

virus free, scanned by sophos

Comment: Try this: removed the AC adapter and the battery, then press and hold the power button for at least 30 seconds. Insert the battery and try booting.

Comment: If the above reset procedure does not fix it, the issue may *still* be a weak battery, unable to provide startup current. Just because it is OEM does not mean it cannot be defective or so old that it cannot provide full current.

Comment: Sorry but this slim laptop does not afford to pull battery.  The battery is embedded in the body of the case, and the hole bottom of the computer needs to be removed to get at the battery.  Battery will run for 4-5 hours after start of computer, so the battery seems fines.  Second battery, and it does hold a charge....